# How to listen focus change in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, focus

In Android, we can call `setOnFocusChangeListener()`, do something in `onFocusChanged()` method, but flutter does not provider `onFocus()` interface like `onTap()` in GestureDetector or `onKey()` in RawKeyboardListener.

I have read flutter api about focus, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusManager-class.html
but I can't find a way to realize my request, anyone who can give me a hand?

Comment: I agree - its hard to understand the intent from the documentation. Example would be great as well.

Comment: [Haider Abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729459) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67089822) saying "You may use MouseRegion() events like [https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) onEnter, onExit"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [FocusNode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) class. Use `addListener` method to add a listener function that listens to focus change.

**Example**
declare and define `FocusNode`

```
 var focusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      print(focusNode.hasFocus);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Use focus node in textfield

```
TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode,
          ),
```

**Output**

when textfield is focus you will get true else false

Comment: Can you provide an example please

Comment: An example please

Comment: without example, answer is USELESS

Answer (score 195):

In addtion you can use [Focus](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Focus-class.html) widget.

```dart
Focus(
  child: TextFormField(...),
  onFocusChange: (hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
      // do stuff
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Certainly cleaner than having to set up and maintain a `FocusNode` instance. And for this post there is a proper example.  Seems this could be the accepted answer now. Nice, Thanks

Comment: This doesn't fire if you tap back.

Comment: @TimSim It did when I tested it (with both TextFormField and TextField).

Comment: It's definitely cleaner but depends on the use case. If we have more than one input field maintaining a focus node for each would be better.

Comment: Almost a must if you're working with blocs and re-usable widgets!

Comment: `onFocusChange` will fire when you lose focus, too. So the variable `hasFocus` is misleading and should be renamed or replace with `_` if you don't use it.

Comment: @chemturion It will fire, but `hasFocus` will evaluate to `true` if the node has focus and `false` if it does not. The name is appropriate. Booleans are typically named with the naming convention has-, is-, did-, etc.

Answer (score 114):

#### Using `FocusNode`

Here is a fully correct answer. `addListener` shall be in `initState()`, not `build()`, because that would result in adding a listener every time a widget is built and you most likely don't want that.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeWidgetState createState() => _SomeWidgetState();
}

class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
    
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      print("Has focus: ${_focusNode.hasFocus}");
    });
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(focusNode: _focusNode);
  }
    
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

#### Using `flutter_hooks` package

If you're by any chance using the [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks) package, there is a dedicated `useFocusNode` hook.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class SomeWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final focusNode = useFocusNode();
    useEffect(() {
      void onFocusChange() {
        print("Has focus: ${focusNode.hasFocus}");
      }
      focusNode.addListener(onFocusChange);
      return () => focusNode.removeListener(onFocusChange);
    }, [focusNode]);

    return TextField(focusNode: focusNode);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Albert221, I was going through this problem of receiving multiple calls, now I managed to solve.

Comment: *Note:* a node focus listener is called twice: when it acquires focus and when it loses the focus. Inside the callback `node.hasFocus` would be `true` or `false` respectively

Comment: @Albert221 Do we also need to call the remove listener in the dispose method ?

Comment: @raphire no, it's not needed. Notifying listeners in a `ChangeNotifer` (which a `FocusNode` is) is illegal after its disposal

Comment: So... why is the second final focusNode in the build method if it's not supposed to be there?... Or it IS supposed to be there, if it's a HookWidget?! 

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård the `useFocusNode` is a hook, that returns the `FocusNode`, but also manages its lifecycle. It's like the first snippet with `initState` and `dispose`, but hidden inside a hook as you can see here: https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks/blob/master/packages/flutter_hooks/lib/src/focus.dart#L50-L79

Comment: Here's a permalink to the hook insides mentioned above, as the previous link no longer works: https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks/blob/70ac6b1aa354547b2c232d7d93ee821a8d74a082/packages/flutter_hooks/lib/src/focus_node.dart#L50

Answer (score -3):

```
class FocusChange {
     static void fieldFocusChange(BuildContext context, FocusNode 
     currentFocusNode,
     FocusNode nextFocusNode) {
     currentFocusNode.unfocus();
     FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nextFocusNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?