# Validate textField when I focus on another textField

Tags: flutter, dart

I need help with this feature. When I enter a text in a textField, I need you to validate that text when I enter another textField.

This is my code

```
    class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
      bool _hasInputError = false;
  var idNumber = '';
  var nombreUser = "";
  FocusNode focusNode;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = new FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          _hasInputError = idNumber.length < 3;
        });
      }
    });
  }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    


        final nombreUserField = TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          onChanged: (String text) {
            nombreUser = text;
          },
        );   
        final idNumberElement = TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorText: _hasInputError ? "Id is too short" : null,
            counterText: "",
          ),
          onChanged: (String tex) {
            idNumber = tex;
          },
        );
        return WillPopScope(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Listener(
                onPointerUp: (e) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        idNumberElement,
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        nombreUserField,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

I tried to make the validation appear in the onEditingComplete but it doesn't work. I Try this answer but it's doesn't work.

[How to listen focus change in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965141/how-to-listen-focus-change-in-flutter)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen focus change in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965141/how-to-listen-focus-change-in-flutter)

Comment: You can also validate on the ```blur``` event. Leaving a field fires a ```blur``` even ton that field.

Answer (score 5):

`initState` should be out of the `build` function. You have declared `initState` inside `build`

```
  FocusNode focusNode;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = new FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          _hasInputError = idNumber.length < 3;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ..
  }
```

Your Code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _focusNode = FocusNode();
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _focusNode.addListener(() {
    if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      if (idNumber.length < 3) {
        "Id is too short";
      }
    }
  });
}
..
}
```

You should also use `setState` to indicate that you have changed the value of `_hasInputError` so that the framework might schedule a build and the user interface for this subtree might be updated to reflect the new state

You have same `FocusNode` object in both `TextField`. Remove the `_focusNode` from `nombreUserField`. `FocusNode` is used to identify a specific `TextField` in Flutter’s focus tree. Every `TextField` should have a different FocusNode.

Comment: You have a condition `idNumber.length < 3`. According to this condition, it is false. Either set  `idNumber.length <= 3` or check if it raises an error for only two characters.

Comment: You have same `focusNode` in both `TextField`. Remove the `_focusNode` from `nombreUserField`.

Comment: But I need to validate those 2 textField

Comment: `FocusNode` is used to identify a specific `TextField` in Flutter’s focus tree. Every `TextFiedl` should have a different `FocusNode`.

Comment: You can create another `FocusNode` named `_anotherFocusNode` and assign it to `nomberUserField`

Comment: I mean, I should have something similar to this:

FocusNode focusNodeidNumber; 
FocusNode focusNodeNameUser;

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should add

```
if(!focusNode.hasfocus){
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Inside the focusNode listener

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

var _focusNode = FocusNode();
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }

    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        if (idNumber.length < 3) "Id is too short";
      }
    });

Answer (score 1):

You need a [BLoC pattern](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/) to manage this.

[This](https://github.com/felangel/bloc) is a fantastic library for BLoC, maintained by [Felix](https://github.com/felangel)

[Here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial) is the sample. This is a login screen example where we check whether the entered text is a valid email or not and password matches some specific criteria.

Though the provided sample is not the exact match that you're looking for, but you can use it as an example to manage your own state.

For Example:

1. You enter a text in TextField1.
2. Now you click TextField2.
3. When the first view loses its focus

> ```
> if(!firstNode.hasfocus){
>     //your code
> }
> ```

Fire an event.

4. If the entered value is invalid display an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can make use of

```
 _formKey.currentState.validate();
```

where `_formKey`, key given to the form

```
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

and the fields has validator property defined.

e.g.

```
     Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {},
              ),
            ],
        ));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. They were asking about validating when focusing *another* text field.