# how to setState() using Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, input, layout, flutter-layout

```
validator: (value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  _casing.depth = 0;
                                } else if (double.tryParse(value) != null) {
                                  // setState(() {
                                  _casing.depth = double.tryParse(value);
                                  // });
                                } else {
                                  _casing.depth = 0;
                                  return kTextFieldError;
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
```

This returns an error that says unable to setState while currently doing so.
What I need is as the user inputs (or finishes either by clicking ok or tapping anywhere which automatically hides keyboard), I want to use the input value to calculate numbers in the parent widget

Comment: In this case you can pass a callback function which will do your job.

on the other hand, you can observe the focus state of the textformfield and do your task.

Comment: how would i observe focus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965141/how-to-listen-focus-change-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `onChanged` property of `TextFormField`

```
onChanged:(value){
 if (value.isEmpty) {
_casing.depth = 0;
} else if (double.tryParse(value) != null) {
 // setState(() {
 _casing.depth = double.tryParse(value);
 // });
 } else {
  _casing.depth = 0;
   return kTextFieldError;
 }
}
```