# TextFormField Focus Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField which is empty by default.
I'm trying to handle the change when the user finishes editing the field (i don't have a confirm button)
How to trigger a function when the TextFormField loses focus ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen focus change in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965141/how-to-listen-focus-change-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a FocusNode to the field and add a listener to it, within the listener you can know if it gains/loses focus.

refer to [How to listen focus change in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965141/how-to-listen-focus-change-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

When you say TextFormField loses focus, I am assuming that whenever the user clicks anywhere other than the TextFormField on the screen, the TextFormField loses focus.

In that case, you can wrap the entire widget with a GestureDetector and inside the onTap function

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: (){}, //call the function here
);
```